# wireframe in 2.8

Tags: wireframe

In 2.8 Wireframe mode is so horrible. Is there a way to get that old wireframe mode?
It is now so difficult to distinguish two overlapped meshes in wireframe mode. Because in 2.8 it's like a half transparent thing or a semisolid thing. I need to set to the early kind of wireframe mode. Is there any way to do that in 2.8?

Comment: Can you try explaining your question briefly or add some images?

Comment: Capture.png
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OCOd6qEFjCAegtQTP9OEm8YsP_g9owtF/view?usp=sharing


Capture2.png

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ptsDqERPUi4uqpbHPE2fceACaZ7NFFkQ

Comment: @Yash Please visit the images above.In the first figure You can see a plane highlighted(which is actually is inside the building). But when I select the building, the plane inside the building is not view able

Comment: Are you saying that the edges are blurred in 2.8 and it was clearer in 2.79.

Comment: Yes. May be there are something I really want to do something to get that in 2.8.

Answer (score 2):

Try Decreasing **X-ray** Opacity,
Click on Shading Drop Down,
[image]
You will see X-ray Bar,
[image]
Take it to 0.000
[image]
Now edges(wires) are much darker.
I know it does not do much work, but it is this according to me.

Comment: I fixed it. I enabled 'show hidden wire' option in overlays drop down menu. So I got the old wire frame mode. Thank you so much for replying

Comment: @Finisoft I didn't find any option like 'show hidden wire', can you add an image of that option so others can also enable it! ;)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QIvKiirGE4-3Pm74ooxiga1zqP6Z6VZ4

Comment: watch the image above

Comment: The "hidden wire" option is missing in 2.82. For anyone wondering you need to unfold the viewport shading options instead and turn on X-Ray with a value of 0 (What Yash said)